# Alert without close option

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog, alert

I am using chrome browser and have installed *ad blocker plus* plugin in it.

When i navigate to a specific page given below.

[Times of India news page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOraF.jpg)

I get a alert on the page, which doesn't have a close option as shown in the screen shot. To remove the alert we need to disable *Ad block plus*. How do we create these kind of alerts and how do we close the alert without disabling *ad block plus*

[image]

Comment: Have you ever tried inspecting the popup with F12 tool?

Comment: It's just a page element, so any Javascript tutorial on how to create elements will do. [Anti-AdBlock Killer](https://reek.github.io/anti-adblock-killer/) takes care of preventing such dialogs, you can ask its author to add this site.

Comment: Asking "how to close the alert" is definitely too broad, as various sites implement it differently. The basic principle is that the webpage can try to monitor if ads loaded properly or gave a network error (which happens when they are blocked), and nag the user if they didn't load under assumption it's blocked.